# history back - return key

Tags: javascript, html, css

How can I return back to the base page by clicking on an image?

Picture1 will be displayed after clicking **First**.
How can I return back to the selection page? (To continue with my selections).

```
<a href="picture1.jpg"> <h3>First</h3></a>
<a href="picture2.jpg"><h3>Secong</h3></a>
```

Comment: selection? You have a link so it goes to the link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of linking to the image file, link to a new HTML file, and place the image on that file using an `<img>` tag. On that same HTML file, you can include a link back to the original page using a `<a>` tag.

**homepage.html**

```
<a href="first-image.html">Go to first image.</a>
<a href="second-image.html">Go to second image.</a>
```

**first-image.html**

```
<a href="homepage.html">Back to Homepage</a>
<img src="picture1.jpg" alt="a photograph of a kitten">
```

**second-image.html**

```
<a href="homepage.html">Back to Homepage</a>
<img src="picture2.jpg" alt="a photograph of a puppy">
```

Answer (score -2):

Here is **result oriented approach** to your question by zooming image to full page and closes on click. I think this is what you need:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('img[data-enlargable]').addClass('img-enlargable').click(function(){
   $("#main").hide();
    var src = $(this).attr('src');
    $('<div>').css({
        background: 'RGBA(0,0,0,.5) url('+src+') no-repeat center',
        backgroundSize: 'contain',
        width:'100%', height:'100%',
        position:'fixed',
        zIndex:'10000',
        top:'0', left:'0',
        cursor: 'zoom-out'
    }).click(function(){
        $(this).remove();
  $("#main").show();
    }).appendTo('body');
});
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head> 
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body> 

<div id="main">
<div>
<h1>First Image</h1><br>
<img data-enlargable width="100" style="cursor: zoom-in"  src="https://i.imgur.com/7KpCS0Y.jpg" />
</div>
<div>
<h1>Second Image</h1><br>
<img data-enlargable width="100" style="cursor: zoom-in"  src="https://media.alienwarearena.com/media/1327-l.jpg" />
</div> 
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: They won't be able to run javascript from a `.jpg` file.

Comment: They're linking to `picture1.jpg`. After a user clicks that link, how are you going to run javascript?

Comment: @curiousBoy `<a href="picture1.jpg">` right there in the question.

Comment: @JohnMontgomery - yes, what is the main idea? Showing an image and get back to where you are on image click! Check my example